# Wordpress status check

Tags: php, wordpress

Do anyone knows how to check the service status for a **wordpress site**

i have search a lot how to monitor a wordpress site, did not find almost nothing !!

For example i have 3 hosts in wordpress site --

```
   www.my_first.com
   www.my_second.com
   www.my_third.com
```

So how can i check those sites status, for example if i have some flash in those sites which is not working somehow or i need to update the version. How can i set up this system check.
Do anyone knows how to monitor the wordpress host status !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor core WordPress updates, plugin updates, and database optimization, then something like this will work:

https://managewp.com/

If you want to know if the server goes down, and more intimate details about the host and server itself (NOT WordPress), then something like:

https://www.pingdom.com/

If you are looking for free... keep searching :)  But this might give you a better idea of what to search for.

As far as I know, there is no service that will tell you if the Flash player installed on someone's machine is broken and refuses to play the Flash files on your website.  If you are really worried about Flash not working (and you should be), then you should consider converting your Flash to HTML5.  Flash is dead...